# Loop through a row in a column and stop when the difference between the current row and previous row is greater than 1

Tags: sql-server, query

[image]

How do I Loop through a row in a column and stop when the difference between the current row and previous row is greater than 1. E.g. (2022-02-06) -(2022-02-04) =2 which is greater than 1.

So, I want only the first two rows to be selected as output.

Comment: don't loop in sql server, work with sets. If you need it, load the content into an application and do the loop there

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: Safe to assume your data is ordered by `ID` or order it by `RECORDTIME`?

Comment: @J.D. is not order by concept it's finding continue date.

Comment: @PiyushKachhadiya Right, and determining which date comes next is based on some order logic. The question is, do we assume that order is by `ID` (if It's guaranteed to be sequential, which is commonplace) or by `RECORDTIME` (as you've assumed in your `ORDER BY` clause in the window function in your answer). Waiting to hear back from OP. My guess is it should be ordered by `ID`.

Answer (score 0):

using `LEAD()` for provides access to a row at a given physical offset that follows the current row.

after use of `DATEDIFF()` unction returns an integer value that represents the difference between the start date and end date, with the date part as the unit.

```
WITH cte
AS
(
    SELECT [recordtime]
    ,      lead([recordtime]) OVER ( ORDER BY [recordtime]) lead_datex
    ,      DATEDIFF(dd,[recordtime],lead([recordtime]) OVER ( ORDER BY [recordtime]) ) AS diff
    FROM [dbo].[tablename]
)
SELECT c.[recordtime]
FROM [cte] AS c
WHERE diff >=1
```